# JQuery UI sortable works only in one direction mouse move in flex-box container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, flexbox

Here is example which shows how JQuery UI sortable works. You need to jiggle 1 block over the 2 to sort. Specifically you need to move previous block downwards over the next one or move next upwards over the previous one.

```
<ul class="items">
  <li class="items__item">1</li>
  <li class="items__item">2</li>
  <li class="items__item">3</li>
  <li class="items__item">4</li>
...
</ul>
```

```
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  list-style: none;
}

.items__item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```
$(function() {
    $('.items').sortable();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cb6etsxg/

Comment: The fiddle seems to work in all directions? what the actual issue you are facing?

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid
Here is the video with trouble
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19g8DWBp-hUBF-lcuJ1M96P-lqxmwfPbY/view?usp=sharing